# Как мне сделать div такой формы, с выпуклыми в середину стенками CSS

Tags: html, css

Пример блока div с выпуклой в середину стенкой
[image: div с выпуклой в середину стенкой]

Я пытался использовать clip-path, но не знаю как сделать стенку выпуклой в середину
Использовать только CSS

Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас фотография открывается?

Comment: @Miha , Да, открываеться. На фото обычный блок, но только верхняя стенка у форме дуги (ямки)

Answer (score 0):

```
.some-div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Дошел к этому сам. Нужно к тому div, который вы хотите изменить, приделать псевдо елемент с border-radius

Comment: А оригинальному блоку .some-div нужно прописать position: relative;